# QGIS Disappearing Buffer

Tags: geometry, qgis, geo

Working in QGIS 3.16.4 on OS Big Sur.  I've created buffers around two vector layers of points, but after dragging/zooming the map, the buffers disappear from the first layer I buffered.  That first buffer layer continues to show in the list of layers (checked) and continues to cover up any other features listed below it on the map.  If I remove the first buffer layer and re-add it, the same thing happens to the second buffer layer I created.  This happens regardless of whether I keep the default layer name for the buffer layers ("temp4") or whether I change each to a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Buffer files are temporary until exported as .shp files. Right click the buffer layer you want to save, then Export -> Save Features As...  Once saved, they no longer disappear.